# Finding the bad Firefox plugin

Tags: firefox, plugins

I'm using firefox with a handfull of plugins, probably like everyone else. Now somehow, firefox locks up a few times a day, with CPU usage going up to 100% and staying there.

Now here's the question: Is there an easy way to find the plugin that causes the problem? I'm particularly looking for an easier way than to disable plugin after plugin and waiting to see what happens.

Is there some way I could attach a debugger (this being on a linux box), or detect what's going on "inside" in another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to find the plugin that causes the problem? I'm particularly looking for an easier way than to disable plugin after plugin

A little easier. Disable *half* the plugins. If symptoms continue then do the other half. Once you have shown which group has the problem, repeat by halving that group. This reduces `n` steps to `log n`.

But all these processes will fail if:

- It is the interaction between two (or more!) plugs.
- It is not an plugin (core FF issue, or maybe an extension, or some mixture across categories).

Comment: It appears there's really no other way around this, as the other responses don't help any further either (as of now). Accepted, and thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've found (after googling for other search terms) the following page, which is quite helpful:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Problematic_extensions

It lists some of the plugins that I'm using as problematic - Firebug, DownThemAll, Adblock Plus - with some good hints and workarounds for some of the problems.

Comment: +1: That's definitely a link worth keeping around.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to to do other than what Richard said. But from now on, try adding add-ons one at a time. It's easy to get excited, add many, and not be sure what is messing up.

Comment: That's not actually what I did.. I don't actually have a lot of plugins, and don't install them "just because", so this behaviour of mine is not the problem.

Answer (score -3):

pleaseeeeeeee.... **PEOPLE**

what you need to do is update the firefox to max and install all the update of the pulgins who come in...

these issues happen due non compatible versions...

Comment: Updating everything does not necessarily make the problem go away.

Comment: It is valid to suggest updating the browser and available plugins as a possible course of action, but to strongly suggest that this _is_ the problem is misleading. There could still be an unstable plugin/extension and this does not help to solve that situation, which is what the OP was asking.